# How to get random entity from H2 database in Java Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2

In my project I create two entities of Car class. These entities are loaded inside h2 database with their unique id. What I want to do is to return randomly chosen entity, like this:

```
@GetMapping("/cars/random"}
Iterable<Cars> getRandomCar(){
return carsRepository.random;
}
```

I know that method body here is incorrect, but I'm just trying to clearly explain what I want to achieve. I don't know how to implement it, and I couldn't find anything online. Maybe someone knows how can I do it?

Comment: I don´t think there is an inbuilt function for this. You could Query your repository with a `count(*)`, then get a random number in in java and access this onbject via findById(). Since you are using a h2 it seams your application is rather small. Maybe it is a viable solution to `repository.findAll()` and the access a random element in the resultion Iterable --> https://www.baeldung.com/java-random-list-element

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [RAND](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#rand) to return a random row from the table.

Create a repository method using the following query.

```
SELECT * FROM CARS ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```